# Google translate script is not running on production env

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I'm using Google Translate for my PHP app.

It works for my local environment but it is not working in production.

When I run "googleTranslateElementInit()" in the web console in production env, it works.

How can I run my code in production?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {            
    console.log('##GOOGLE TRANSLATE IS RUNNING');          
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
      {
        pageLanguage: 'en', 
        includedLanguages: 'en,es,pt', 
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
      }, 
      'google_translate_element');
  }                  
  googleTranslateElementInit();
</script>
```

Comment: is `$_GET['google'] == 1` ?

Comment: There's no way that what you've provided above runs without errors

Comment: yeah 'google' == 1. I put ?google=1 in the url.

Comment: @PatrickQ why do you say that?

Comment: Because it's true.  What you have above generates a parse error.  So that's obviously not the exact code that you're running.

Comment: @PatrickQ While that is not the exact code I'm running (I do include the curly brace to end the if statement if that's your concern. )  My concern is with the javascript function not the php.

Comment: If you're having the same problem when you remove any PHP, then you should remove the PHP from the code your question and the PHP tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function ran when I executed it in the web console, after the entire page was loaded, I just put the function inside of `$(window).load(function(){ //code })` and it worked.